# How to convert Address from user input into LatLng Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to convert a users input in Edit text to LatLng when the Search button is clicked. This will then update the camera and move tot hat position.
Here is my code in the main:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Locations;
using System.Linq;


namespace SafeandSound
{
[Activity(Label = "SafeandSound", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);


        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        SetUpMap();
    }
    private void SetUpMap()
    {
        if (mMap == null)
        {
            FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.map);
        }
    }

    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mMap = googleMap;

    }
    // Button to Search for Address//
    public void onMapSearch(View view)
    {
        EditText address = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.searchText);
         var addressnew = address.Text;
        if (addressnew != null)
        {
            addressnew = address.Text;
        }
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this);
        IList<Address> coordinates = geoCoder.GetFromLocationName(addressnew, 0);
        Address gotAddress = coordinates.FirstOrDefault();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(gotAddress.Latitude, gotAddress.Longitude);
        CameraPosition.Builder builder = CameraPosition.InvokeBuilder();
        builder.Target(latLng);
        builder.Zoom(10);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = builder.Build();
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(cameraPosition);

    }
}
}
```

When I use this right now, I get an exception error. Please HELP!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to check if the `Geocoder` service is available on the device/emulator via the static method:

```
Geocoder.isPresent
```

Note: The use of Geocoder requires Internet access and Google Play services to be installed...

Next you are requesting zero results in the "maxResults" parameter:

```
GetFromLocationName(addressnew, 0);
```

> int: max number of results to return. Smaller numbers (1 to 5) are recommended

Also you might need to retry the request to obtain results. You should not hammer the service as you will get throttled. Use a retry delay that  increasing after each attempt.

#### Example:

```
if (!Geocoder.IsPresent)
{
    Log.Error("SO", "Geocoder is not present");
}
else
{
    var geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
    var retry = 0;
    do
    {
        var addressList = await geocoder.GetFromLocationNameAsync("Starbucks 523 Pine Street, Seattle, WA, 98101", 5);
        if (addressList.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var address in addressList)
            {
                Log.Debug("SO", $"{address.Latitude}:{address.Longitude} - {address.FeatureName} : {address.GetAddressLine(0)} : {address.GetAddressLine(1)}");
            }
            break;
        }
        retry++;
        Log.Warn("SO", $"No addresses returned...., retrying in {retry * 2} secs");
        await Task.Delay(retry * 1000);
    } while (retry < 5);
}
```

#### Output:

```
[SO] 47.611423:-122.337519 - Starbucks : Starbucks : 400 Pine Street
[SO] 47.611848:-122.335693 - Starbucks : Starbucks : 515 Pine Street
```

Comment: Okay! but how would I implement that with an Edit Text variable? I am asking for user input and then changing it to LatLng.

Comment: @S.Cvija Take the user's input from `EditText.Text` and use it as the parameter to `geocoder.GetFromLocationNameAsync(xxxxxx, 5)`

Comment: I have applied your code and it is still giving me that "An unhandled exception has occurred"

Comment: @S.Cvija Post another question with your code that is throwing the exception

Comment: I posted the new question. Thanks!